# Centering the JTabbedPane but not the actual tabs

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

How would I go about making the length of the tabs automatically resize based on how much room is left in that row of tabs.

Picture:

[image]

As you can see the tab's width is based off the text in the tab.

If you need me to explain what I want better then just ask me because I don't know if I made it clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom component and set it's preferred size. For example, in `ButtonTabComponent` of [`TabComponentsDemo`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html):

```
label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(...));
```

You have to choose an appropriate dimension based on other aspects of your layout, so it won't be automatic.

> I want to define a size for the actual tabbed pan.

The size of the `JTabbedPane` is a function of the dimensions and `LayoutManager` of the `Container` to which it has been added. In the [example cited](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html), the default layout of the frame's content pane is `BorderLayout`, and `add(pane)` adds it to the center by default.

To accomplish your goal, I see two approaches:

1. Divide the current width of the enclosing `Container` among the existing tabs and repaint the tabbed pane, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158757).
2. Develop your own implementation of [`TabbedPaneUI`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/TabbedPaneUI.html) and interpret `SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT` accordingly.

Comment: I don't want to define a size for the tabs in the tabbed pane. I want to define a size for the actual tabbed pan.

Comment: @Gnarly: I've elaborated above.

Comment: Thanks but the things you listed are a bit too overkill for something so simple. I guess it doesn't really matter if I make my tabbed pan like this anyways.

Comment: @Gnarly: The design lets you easily use a custom tab component with its own layout; try changing the layout for `ButtonTabComponent` to see the effect. `JTabbedPane` doesn't let you change the inter-tab layout, as it must handle side-scrolling itself.