# Add a JButton inside a JTabbedPane tab

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding a button component to a java tabbed pane in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901609/adding-a-button-component-to-a-java-tabbed-pane-in-java)

Is it possible to add a button to a JTabbedPane tab (the tab itself) so that when clicked it could perform an action, for example close the tab?

Answer (score 3):

Sure. First add a tab like this:

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.add( "title", content );
```

Then change the "title" label with this:

```
tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt( 0, new JButton( "This is now a button!" ) );
// 0 is the tabindex
```

Comment: I don't think that this what the OP asked for. I think that it would like to have a close button like you have in Web-browsers.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, I want to button inside the tab, like in the browser when you click the cross.